# Lotus Notes: display multi value field in single view row

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

in lotus notes i have multi values field, for ex.:

`multivaluefied(0)=value0`
`multivaluefied(1)=value1`
`multivaluefied(2)=value2`

and i want to display all values  in a single view row and column like:    `value0,value1,value2`

thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really see the problem, as this is the default behaviour for a view column containing a multi value field.
The only thing to change is the separator for display:

Just enter `multivaluefield` as formula (or even easier: select the field name from the field list) for the column and select `Comma` as `Multi-value separator` in the properties of the column (first tab).

EDIT: Make sure, that `Show multiple values as separate entries` on the second tab of the properties is NOT checked (by default it isn't, but probably you copied a column from somewhere else...)

Comment: i try to do your solution but i can see only first value of multivalue field in the same row, and i want to dysplay all values in the same row.

Comment: i don't have "Show multiple values as separate entries" selected

Comment: I do not know if it can be useful but i'm using notes 6.5.6

Comment: Ok, i found the error. In the sixth tab of column properties, in the programmic use tab, i change the "name" properties with a name different from the name of the multi value field and now it works ! Thank's

Comment: Yes, the name property sometimes causes that "strange" behaviour.